# vb.net sorting list(of T) based on class property

Tags: vb.net, sorting, collections

I'm currently working on a project that implements the usage of a `List(of T)`. And i'm trying to sort the list.

The collection is based on class `PDF_Document`

```
Public Class PDF_Document
    Public FullFilePath As String
    Public Property Size As String
    Public Property DocNumber As String
    Public Property Sequence As String
    Public Property Revision As String
End Class
```

When the collection is filled, it should sort the collection on the sequence number. `001, 002, 003, 004, ...`

But how do you sort a collection based on that property?

Comment: Why do you store such a number as string at all? If you want to diplay that number formatted with leading zeros, format it when you diplay it, f.e. with `sequence.ToString("D3")` but don't store it as string.

Comment: `myList.OrderBy(Function (z) z.Sequence).ToList()`  If it is not all numerals you may have to do it differently.

Comment: This has been the way of document numbering at my work since.. years before I have been working here. It's weird I know but our customers implement it also most of the time so I guess it's not uncommon?

Comment: You should look at the "Related questions" on the right side, there's a few questions about this already.

Comment: How they choose to represent it and how you manage it in code can be 2 different things.

Comment: @Plutonix okay, I see your point, I added a variable `Public RealSequence As Double` so the sequence number is converted and sorted with this variable. Don't really know if this is a correct method to apply what you suggested? But it works with the answer given below.

Comment: Double?  as in `123.4` (decimals)?  Integer seems more appropriate.  If you have code to determine the next value (or find last) you definitely want it as a numeric though.

Comment: Yes Integer is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you store such a number as string at all? If you want to diplay that number formatted with leading zeros, format it when you diplay it, f.e. with `sequence.ToString("D3")` but don't store it as string.

If you want to sort the original list you can use [`List(Of T).Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
pdfList.Sort(Function(pdf1, pdf2)
                 Return pdf1.Sequence.CompareTo(pdf2.Sequence)
             End Function)
```

If you don't want to modify the original list you can use LINQ:

```
Dim ordered = From pdf In pdfList Order By pdf.Sequence
```

You can create a new list with `ToList`, f.e.:

```
Dim orderedPdfList = ordered.ToList()
```

Otherwise you always have to parse the string to `Int32`:

```
Dim ordered = From pdf In pdfList Order By Int32.Parse(pdf.Sequence)
```